# Help me get my free coffee!

Tags: wordplay, word-game

I just reached my desk and I noticed a piece of paper in front of my computer, reading :

> Antimissile demander
>   Flamboyant dollars
>   Subchapter unclassified
>   Bladed fundamental
>   Impersonated babels
>
> Free coffee at this afternoon break if you find the relation!

These words don't make sense to me, although the five phrases seem grammatically correct.

Can you help me find the connection between these words? *(Not that I am addicted to coffee but hey, if it's free...)*

Comment: Is this a connection for each line or a single connection for the whole thing?

Comment: I wanted to put it at first in the post but was afraid of making it to simple. Anyway, there is a connection for each pair of words, which is the same for all the pairs. You find one, you find the other ones.

Comment: I seriously thought (hoped) this would be in The Workplace. Similar logos and all...

Comment: @Fiksdal I'm still hoping that the free coffee story is real. :D

Comment: Very nice puzzle

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Each pair of words

> contains a synonym of "boy" in one word and "girl" in another.

Antimissile demander

> miss and man

Flamboyant dollars

> boy and doll

Subchapter unclassified

> chap and lass

Bladed fundamental

> lad and dame

Impersonated babels

> son and babe

Comment: first time I see "chap" and "lass" but upvote for nice answer (even if no correct)

Comment: 'chap' and 'lass' are very common synonyms for man and woman in the UK

Comment: Just came back from the break and you were right ;) good job! Now I can enjoy my free coffee :P

Comment: @lois6b Surely you've heard of the dog Lassie before.

Comment: Yeah, the dog but I thought it was just a name

Comment: I seriously wonder how did you even notice that?

Comment: @Arth I wouldn't say *very* common, but common enough to be considered in use. Also I think 'lass' is probably more of a Scottish thing, even if only stereotypically. "How yae doin' ya wee bonnie lass?"

Comment: @PascalvKooten fo you mean my answer? Actually the first thing I saw was "Ant man" in the first pair of words. that got me thinking of superheroes, but led me to finding the correct answer via a similar technique.

Comment: @Pharap Yes, perhaps 'very well-known' would have been a better way of putting it!